# How to get binary representation of Int in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, binary, bit

Is there a method that can be used to get an Integer's representation in bits? For example when provided:
0 gives 0
4 gives 100
22 gives 10110

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Method 1:**
Use `Integer.toBinaryString(a)` where `a` is an Int. This method is from the Java platform and can be used in Kotlin.
Find more about this method at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)

*Note*: This method works for both positive and negative integers.

**Method 2:**
Use `a.toString(2)` where `a` is an Int, `2` is the radix
*Note*: This method only works for positive integers.

Comment: Beware negative numbers though. `(-2).toString(2)` will be `-10` instead of `11111111111111111111111111111110`. So you get the number in [base-2 numeral system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) rather than its [2-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) bit representation.

Comment: @ilya How do we deal with negative Ints then?

Comment: @RashiKaranpuria you have to interpret that info using the negative sign in the string representation. Since 2's complement is not available(at least right now) there is no other way of cleanly managing that in my opinion. llya correct me if I missed something. (I am new to Kotlin, might have missed the fine print somewhere)

Comment: If you want leading zeros: `Integer.toBinaryString(1).padStart(Int.SIZE_BITS, '0')` (added an answer with more details).

Comment: @RashiKaranpuria To get 2-complement representation you could perform `a.xor(4294967295)` where `4294967295` is the number where all the bits are 1 (i.e.  1111...1)

Answer (score 36):

Starting with Kotlin 1.3 the binary representation of a signed integer can be obtained by reinterpreting it as an unsigned one and converting it to string base 2:

```
a.toUInt().toString(radix = 2)
```

Comment: As of 1.4 this will still generate the warning `This declaration is experimental and its usage should be marked with '@kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes`.

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 13):

I wanted a function that prints out the 32-bit binary representation of all the bits of the integer. The standard library functions mentioned in the other answers do not do this. However, it can be done by combining [`Integer.toBinaryString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) as Rashi Karanpuria pointed out with the Kotlin stdlib function [`padStart()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-start.html):

```
fun Int.to32bitString(): String =
    Integer.toBinaryString(this).padStart(Int.SIZE_BITS, '0')

fun main() {
    println(Int.MIN_VALUE.to32bitString())
    println((-1).to32bitString())
    println(0.to32bitString())
    println(1.to32bitString())
    println(Int.MAX_VALUE.to32bitString())
}
```

Output:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
11111111111111111111111111111111
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000001
01111111111111111111111111111111
```

---

An equivalent method if you don't have access to [`Integer.toBinaryString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)): `Int.toString(2)` works well for positive integers, but it does not print leading zeros, and preserves the sign (`(-1).toString(2)` returns `"-1"` instead of a string of `1` bits). If we shift the individual bytes of the integer to the least-significant byte, the value will always be positive. We can use `Int.toString(2)` to get a representation of each byte individually, then join them back together (works for `Long` too):

```
fun Int.toBinaryString(): String = let { int ->
    IntProgression
        .fromClosedRange(rangeStart = Int.SIZE_BITS - 8, rangeEnd = 0, step = -8)
        .joinToString("") { bytePos ->
            (int shr bytePos and 0xFF).toString(2).padStart(8, '0')
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this method to convert integer to binary,

```
fun Int.toBinary(len: Int): String {
    return String.format("%" + len + "s", this.toString(2)).replace(" ".toRegex(), "0")
}
```

Call this method like this,
numberToBeConvert.toBinary(length)

```
4.toBinary(8) = 00000100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have bigger numbers than Integer, you can use BigInteger.

```
val binaryString = BigInteger("12345678987654321").toString(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use pure Kotlin and binary representation must have a fixed length. For example, if you want to get **00111111** (63) you can do it like this:

```
fun UByte.toBinary(): String {
    return buildString(8) {
        val binaryStr = this@toBinary.toString(2)
        val countOfLeadingZeros = 8 - binaryStr.count()
        repeat(countOfLeadingZeros) {
            append(0)
        }
        append(binaryStr)
    }
}
```

You may modify that code to use it with UInt. However, make sure you use it with an unsigned type.